# Prevent line break in title from being displayed in header

Tags: header-footer, line-breaking, titles

I'm writing a document that contains an ampersand in the title that I'd rather not remove, and I've inserted a line break just to make things look a little nicer. However, every odd-numbered page now displays the break as a large white space. Is there any way to remove this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}             

\title{This is the first part of my title \&\\ This is the second}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

This is my document page 1. 

\newpage

This is my document page 2. 

\newpage

This is my document page 3. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\title` command accepts an optional argument to set the title text to be displayed in the header:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}             

\title[This is the first part of my title \& This is the second]
        {This is the first part of my title \&\\ This is the second}

\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

This is my document page 1. 

\newpage

This is my document page 2. 

\newpage

This is my document page 3. 

\end{document}
```

[image]